# How do I extract the entire array from a document in a collection that matches the given criteria?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to enter a query that matches a userId and a folderId inside of my Folders collection. Once I find that specific document, I want to extract only the placeList array but the ENTIRE placeList array.

[image]

This is where I am at now after trying a few different combinations of queries:

```
const result = await db.collection('Folders').aggregate
        ([
            {$match: {
                "userId": uid,
                "folderId": fid
            }},
            {$unwind: "$placeList"},
        
        ]);
```

How can I extract the entire placeList array from a matching document in my collection?

Comment: You can just project the placeList array field , why you need to $unwind it? https://mongoplayground.net/p/im8qfIMMHCJ

Comment: @R2D2 I tried $unwind in hopes that it would generate the return needed since the solution in that link didn't work either. I think I tried that solution earlier but forgot to put .toArray() after. Thanks!